# multipart/mixed not working in thunderbird and hotmail but Gmail

Tags: php, pdf, mime

Following is the source codes of the email that my thunderbird received.
I cannot find any syntax errors and it work well in gmail.
But for hotmail and thunderbird the attachment is broken and the content is blank....
I had tried a long time to solve this problem. Any help?

```
Subject: MySubject
From: testing@test.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="02f05ee7d40220f0ebab50ef7440ca55"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Cc: cc@cc.com
Message-Id: <20161123030114.97B04DCD682@server.com>
Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2016 11:01:14 +0800 (MYT)


--02f05ee7d40220f0ebab50ef7440ca55
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
<p>Test</p>

--02f05ee7d40220f0ebab50ef7440ca55
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="Attachment.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Attachment.pdf"
PDF ATTACHMENT CODES HERE
PDF ATTACHMENT CODES HERE
PDF ATTACHMENT CODES HERE
PDF ATTACHMENT CODES HERE
PDF ATTACHMENT CODES HERE
--02f05ee7d40220f0ebab50ef7440ca55--
```

Comment: In the parts the empty line between headers and contents seems to be missing.

Comment: And an overall CTE 7bit does not work well with a mime part CTE 8bit.

Comment: @mkl Oh my god you are my life saver!! I think you should write down your answer below and let me choose it as best answer for others convenient.
Thanks you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mkl for his answer.
After some modified, my codes had work!!

***`"There must be a empty line between header and content."`***
is the point

```
Subject: MySubject
From: testing@test.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="02f05ee7d40220f0ebab50ef7440ca55"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Cc: cc@cc.com
Message-Id: <20161123030114.97B04DCD682@server.com>
Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2016 11:01:14 +0800 (MYT)


--02f05ee7d40220f0ebab50ef7440ca55
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<p>Test</p>

--02f05ee7d40220f0ebab50ef7440ca55
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="Attachment.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Attachment.pdf"

PDF ATTACHMENT CODES HERE
PDF ATTACHMENT CODES HERE
PDF ATTACHMENT CODES HERE
PDF ATTACHMENT CODES HERE
PDF ATTACHMENT CODES HERE
--02f05ee7d40220f0ebab50ef7440ca55--
```

Comment: As mentioned above, an overall CTE 7bit in combination with a mime part CTE 8bit means asking for trouble in the long run..